# Calculating values from several items

Tags: c, function

I am trying to log a process in C and I need an simpler solution.

I have a status byte of which each bit indicates if certain equipment is on. Each equipment has a fixed power consumption rate and I want to log the power usage based on its ON/OFF status.

So, I have a struct called equip_totals and the usage rates as members, equip1...

```
struct {
        unsigned int equip1;
        unsigned int equip2;
        ...
        } equip_totals;
```

and to update, I use a rather long function which I would like to simplify

```
void update_equip_status(char *equip_status)
{
if (&equip_staus = 0x01)
equip_totals.equip1 = consumption_rate*time;
if...
}
```

If you have any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace equip_totals with array and use the following loop

```
void update_equip_status(char *equip_status) {
    for ( int i = 0; equip_status; i++ ) {
        if ( equip_status & 1 )
            equip_totals[i] = consumption_rate*time;
        equip_status >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: why to thank when you have an ability to upvote the answer or even better - to accept it

Answer (score 2):

use a simple array: `unsigned int equip_totals[8];`

also, it would be better to simply pass `equip_status` by value.

```
for(int i=0; equip_status != 0; i++, equip_status /= 2)
   if (equip_status & 1)
      equip_totals[i] = consumption_rate*time;
```

Comment: I have thought about that, but thats not the problem. I want  to update in one shot with equip_status..instead of writing an update for every combination..